# NPM install Laravel-Mix gives error: "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-mix

I've been trying to install npm on laravel but it keeps giving "Maximum call stack size exceeded". So i decided to install the modules individually and it all worked except for the Laravel-Mix. I've tried updating NPM and force clear cache but it still keeps giving:

"Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Npm Version:6.8.0
Node Js Version: v10.15.1

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.2",
    "sass": "^1.17.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.6"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.
I installed node with all additional tools again. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to repeat the command `npm install` two or three times, until it exit without errors.
Side note: if you are on Windows use `npm install --no-bin-links`

Comment: tried it many times. still the same error "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: Try to remove the node_modules directory

Comment: done that ,, and when i try npm install still the same

Comment: last advice: delete node_modules dir and package-lock.json file. If it still does not work I have no more advices.

Comment: where can i find the package-lock.json file

Comment: Near the package.json file in the root of your Laravel directory structure

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

`npm uninstall laravel-mix`

`npm cache clean --force`

`npm i`

or:

`npm rebuild`

`npm rebuild -g`